# How to close a pop up window just by clicking it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a pop up window that opens a bigger copy of the image that is clicked on. This is the html code for it:

```
<img src="images/car1_1.jpg" alt="interior" id=Upics onClick="MM_openBrWindow('images/car1_1.jpg','CARPOP','width=500em,height=500em')" />
```

The jquery/script for the pop up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
//-->
</script>
```

Is there a way that the window is closed when it is clicked on?

Comment: If one of the solutions answers you question please accept it, otherwise please provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript's `window.close()` closes the window the script is attached to. In your case, if you add this js code to your popup's script, you can close its window from a click event, like this:

**main.html**

```
<img src="images/car1_1.jpg" alt="interior" id=Upics onClick="MM_openBrWindow('popup.html','CARPOP','width=500em,height=500em')"/>
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Click me</title>
</head>

<body onClick="closePopup()">
  <img src="images/car1_1.jpg" alt="interior"/>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function closePopup() {
  window.close();
}
</script>
```

Tweak the CSS if the image isn't covering the whole page.

Comment: You'll have to make sure your div captures the click event though.

Comment: Oh the URL of the popup is not directed towards a page you wrote? If not, you should add that to your original post.

Comment: I really dont understand what do you mean

Comment: Well the popup you open is an HTML page, right? Did you create it and do you have access to its source code?

Comment: Its not really an HTML page I created, a larger picture will be on a pop up window when the smaller image is created

Comment: Oh it's simply an image? well you can write a simple html file with the image inside it and open the html page instead of the image directly and attach the event to the popup's body like I did in solution 1.

Comment: Simply place an `<img src="yourImgUrl"></img>` tag instead of the `<!-- You popup content -->` comment.

Comment: Please check most recent edit for the full explanation

Comment: I tried creating a new page plus linking the original to the old one. It worked for the pop up but didn't for the close function.

Comment: Could you try to put the `onClick` event Handler to the `img` tag instead of the `body`?

Comment: I even tried moving the onClick to the img. Still nothing

Comment: Just a question. Why linking the script to both the img and body tag? Isn't the img part of the body?

Comment: Yeah it's just that I'm never sure exactly in what order are mouse event captured and some elements don't pass the event to others. Maybe body is enough, maybe img is enough, I don't know I don't have an html environment to try with me (or I'm too lazy to start one). With both, you're sure it will fire, at least for the test, you can refine afterwards.

Comment: Ok actually, I just tried. onClick on img is enough.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a variable/reference to your popup, like this for instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var myPopup;

function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  myPopup = window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
//-->
</script>
```

Then elsewhere you can do a call:

```
myPopup.close();
```

Comment: what do you mean elsewhere?

Comment: You can pass that statement to an event handler, or something.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:
 Use the windoe.close() Method

```
  popup_window = window.open("");

  popup_window.close ();
```

**Solution 2:**
You can close the current window using self.close ();

Comment: How can I close the current window?

Answer (score 0):

First I stored the popup reference in a variable called `imgPopup`. Wrote a click event on body to close the popup `imgPopup.close()`. I am checking if the reference exists before calling `close()` function. If you click anywhere on the current window, the popup will be closed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgPopup;
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  imgPopup = window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Close the window when we click on the body.
    jQuery('body').click(function() { 
        if (imgPopup) {
            imgPopup.close(); 
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't just paste code without writing anything next to it like that.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat - I put in comments what I am doing. I am closing the new window, when we click on the current window (current window's body). If that is not enough, I can write it more clearly.

Comment: yes, please add a bit of text beforehand to explain what you are showing. Especially, what part of the code makes it different, or what are the differences between OP's code and yours to make it easier to read.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat - Thank you. I added description.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myWindow;
var count = 0;
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) {
    myWindow =   window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}

$("body").on("click",function(){
    var url  =  $("body").find('img').attr('src') || "";
    if(url != "" && count == 0){
        count = 1;
    }else{
        count = 0;
        myWindow.close();
    }

})
```

if you click any where except on the image, the modal window is closed

Comment: Hm, I think OP wants the popup to close when the **popup** is clicked on, not the main window.